# What nouns describe the relationship between tiers?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in the majority of football (soccer) leagues, you'll have a number of tiers such as the first division, second division, third, etc. At the end of each season the few top teams in the second division are promoted to the first division, and the few bottom teams in the first division are relegated to the second division.

What would the second division be refered to from the first division, and visa versa?

I don't think parent/child necessarily makes sense, as this to my mind indicates some level of succession and timing, such as the parenting occuring before the child, where as in this context they are potentially conceived and occur at the same time.

EDIT:

To clarify I'm looking for the noun, such as:

- The first division is the **parent** of the second division.
- The second division is the **child** of the first division.

Comment: Team-above; team-below ?

Comment: Well I'm thinking I may have to concede there isn't a perfect set of nouns for this and go with something like that, although I'm describing the competition or the league rather than the team.

Comment: I should have said *league-above/up/after/+1* or *league-up/below/down/-1* but same principle :-) hopefully someone has a better idea !

Comment: Clubs are promoted and demoted, and they are said to go *up a level* or *down a level*.

Comment: Considering maybe Senior/Junior

Comment: Seen from above, all but the top division could be "lesser" or "lower"

From below, the rest might be "higher" but I know more about paint drying than sports…

Comment: superior/inferior?

Comment: If you read writing about British football, such as on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_football_league_system), you'll see the British terminology, which is based on height metaphors: top, higher, upper, lower, etc.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone cares about such an old question, but it seems just wrong to me to ask for a *noun* to describe a relationship - a relationship is a noun already and we generally use adjectives (sometimes adverbs) to describe relationships between nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a traditional score table (like in an arcade video game, or pub darts). Someone is at the top, and someone at the bottom, and some others in the middle. Let's call each of those someones a "member", belonging to the "table".

The division system is just like that, except that you have multiple systems of "members" in "tables" (the 1st division is a table of members, and the 2nd division is a table of members, etc.) and then the entire system is a "meta-table", itself, where each member is a table, and you can rank them the same way: that's why the first division is "higher" than the second division, etc. I hope this doesn't sound pretentious. It makes perfect sense.

From a computer programming perspective: you are right that this isn't a parent-child relationship, because a child is generally PART of the parent (e.g. a rocket engine might be a child of a parent rocket-ship). You are talking about a table of tables. So the relationship from div 1 to div 2 is just "next" and "previous", and there is also an assumption that "being more previous than X means you have done better in football than X". Boring, but true.

Answer (score 1):

Since a lower tier can send a team up as well as receive a team that was "relegated" from a higher tier, there's a reciprocal relationship that no single noun would express. You'd need two nouns for all but the highest and lowest tiers.